# Can't pass instance variable to another method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, controller, instance

I cannot access the `@quiz` instance variable in the `new` method.

I need to access `@quiz` in the view corresponding to the `new` method.

@edit I've tried to bypass the problem, by `@quiz` once again in new method, but `params[:session][:test_password]` is empty for some reason.

```
class QuizzesController < ApplicationController
  include UsersHelper
  before_action :logged_in_user

  def password_check
  end

  def forward
    find_quiz
    if @quiz
      redirect_to new_quiz_path
    else
      redirect_to root_url
      flash[:danger] = t(:invalid_test_password)
    end
  end

  def new
    @score = Score.new
  end

  private

    def find_quiz
      @quiz = Test.find_by(password: params[:session][:test_password])
    end

end
```

routes in this controllers:

```
quiz_password GET    (/:locale)/quiz_password(.:format)  quizzes#password_check {:locale=>/pl|en/}
              POST   (/:locale)/quiz_password(.:format)  quizzes#forward {:locale=>/pl|en/}
         quiz GET    (/:locale)/quiz(.:format)           quizzes#new {:locale=>/pl|en/}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Actually, you aren't even asking a question, you are just making a statement and showing some code. What is your question? Do you get an error? If yes, what is it? Do you get wrong output? If yes, what is it and what would be the right output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mistakenly thought `params[:session][:test_password]` was correct way to save variable into session. I have assigned `session[:test_password] = params[:session][:test_password]` instead and it works just fine

```
class QuizzesController < ApplicationController
  include UsersHelper
  before_action :logged_in_user

  def password_check
  end

  def forward
    @quiz = Test.find_by(password: params[:session][:test_password])
    if @quiz
      store_password
      redirect_to quiz_path
    else
      redirect_to root_url
      flash[:danger] = t(:invalid_test_password)
    end
  end

  def new
    find_quiz
    @score = Score.new
  end

  private

    def store_password
      session[:test_password] = params[:session][:test_password]
    end

    def find_quiz
      @quiz = Test.find_by(password: session[:test_password])
    end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that each request is processed by an independent ActionController instance so any instance variables set on one request will be trashed by the time the second one comes around. You can only persist data in things like `session`, the filesystem, or some kind of database.

What you should do here is make better use of the methods you already have:

```
before_action :find_quiz, only: [ :forward, :new ]
```

Then there's no need to trigger that method manually, it will happen before each request directed to that action automatically. When that method runs that variable will populate.

Comment: I see that you answered while I was editing main post. Please read edited part.

Comment: The `new` method there does not call `find_quiz` either explicitly or implicitly via `before_action` so there's your problem.

Comment: Not really. I wrote in the edited part that I tried that and it didn't work, because `params[:session][:test_password]` is being reset.

Comment: It's not being reset. Maybe it's not being assigned. Check `log/development.log` to see what's going on, something you should have open whenever you're doing Rails work.

Comment: You're correct. My mistake was that I thought `params[:session][:test_password]` was correct way to save it, but it wasn't. I have used `session[:test_password]` and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect the user, a new request is made. Because of that all variables are deleted and you will need to create them again.

Comment: I've tried to recreate `@user` variable in `new` method but `params[:session][:test_password]` is empty, for some reason it's being reset.

Comment: That's because you must send the parameter again in the second request.

Comment: The point of that method is to pass this variable to the next view and generate view depending what `test_password` user enters. So I can't really do that.

Comment: You should use [sessions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session) for that.

Comment: I mistakenly thought params[:session][:test_password] was correct way to save it into session, but it wasn't. I have used `session[:test_password]` instead and it works just fine.